SPSS Multicollinearity Binary Logistic
Just a quick one - I am running a binary logistic regression in SPSS and I wanted to check the VIF for multicollinearity. How do you do this when the dependent variable is binary - is it a case of just running the collinearity diagnostics in the linear model?
Also, I noticed that my VIFs change when I run them with different dependent variables, yet the same independent variables. I wondered why this would be the case as I thought only the latter mattered for VIFs?

VIFs are solely a function of the independent variables, they should not change with a different dependent variable. So you can get them by running your model as if the dependent variable were continuous.
However, the threshold for troublesome VIF is quite a bit lower, although I don't know if there is real consensus on how low. See Auslander's answer in this thread
I don't have SPSS but here is some R code showing that the DV doesn't matter:
library(car)

set.seed(1234)


x1 <- rnorm(1000)
x2 <- x1 + rnorm(1000,0, 2)
x3 <- x1 + x2 + rnorm(1000, 0, 2)
y <- x1 + 3*x2 + 2*x2 + rnorm(1000,0, 4)

m1 <- lm(y~x1 + x2 + x3)
vif(m1)  #1.59, 2.47, 2.99

y2 <- as.numeric(cut(y,2))
m2 <- lm(y2~x1+x2+x3)
vif(m2) #1.59, 2.47, 2.99

As an aside, my dissertation showed that condition indexes may be better than VIF, but I did not look at logistic regression.

Thanks so much that is very helpful! I have also seen that you can run a bivariate analysis and see whether the coefficients are < .8 (a rule of thumb!). I just wondered is this still possible for IVs such as 'gender', coded as a 1/0

That's not a good way of looking at collinearity.  You can have collinearity without high correlation.
